# Defining and using external functions ruby-xslt

Tags: xslt

Has anyone got experience using ruby-xslt gem?

I have it transforming XML perfectly but now I want to add an external function call which is proving very difficult. The documentation for this is a little light and the example provided makes no sense to me at all... see http://ruby-asp.rubyforge.org/ruby-xslt/files/README.html

I am defining my function as:

```
XML::XSLT.registerExtFunc("mynamespace","my-function") do |arg|
      #do something interesting
end
```

In my stylesheet I do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="mynamespace:my-function(/)"/>
```

and I get the error:

```
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function my-function bound to undefined prefix mynamespace
```

Comment: Can you post your xsl:stylesheet element please?

Comment: I think I have found my problem. I will post full details in a moment, I never registered the namespace in the stylesheet - now I have my external function is getting called.

Comment: That was exactly my thought :)

Comment: Ok - don't have a high enough reputation to answer my question right now. Nothing exists on the internet to show how to do external functions with this gem. I'll post the solution tomorrow that matched up with the question.

Comment: Just wait until you have high enough rep to do it.